# Did Denethor take out the orcs and their war machines when he fell?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

When Denethor leapt, flaming, from the top of that castle, did he kill any orcs or set any of their war machines ablaze when he landed? I really hope he did, it would have been a good redemption for him.

Comment: Please note this is the movie only. In the book, he was burned in the Houses of the Dead and did not leap from anywhere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem terribly likely - the rock outcrop he jumps from doesn't extend past the city's outer wall, and even at a full run, he wouldn't have travelled too far from the base of the outcrop.

More than likely, he would have landed amongst the soldiers fighting to defend the first gate - and would have likely further decreased their morale at a crucial moment (though, they probably would not have realised it was Denethor, having a flaming body splatter in your midst wouldn't be cheerful).

[image: Model of Minas Tirith]

Comment: That is a horrible realization.

Comment: For even more horrible, read the book - there's no redemption whatsoever, and something involving a Palatir (that I don't want to spoil on you so I'm not going to say any more).

Comment: Actually at the time of Denethor's fall the main gate had been captured and Gandalf had fallen back to another position.

Answer (score 1):

Well it didn't really happen, so no. Just PJ and his revising for effect on the audience....

Comment: You mean "really" like the bit in the books *really* happened?